# Pandas - avoid iterrows() assembling a multi-index data frame from another time-series multi-index data frame

Tags: python, pandas

For analyzing pairs of currencies, I have two dataframes. The first one contains information about the symbols constituting every unique pair (as in "pair metadata"):

```
    X           Y           handle
0   ETHEUR E3   XMRUSD E3   ETHEUR E3_XMRUSD E3
1   ETHEUR E3   TRXETH E3   ETHEUR E3_TRXETH E3
2   ETHEUR E3   ETHUSD E3   ETHEUR E3_ETHUSD E3
3   ETHEUR E3   BTCEUR E3   ETHEUR E3_BTCEUR E3
4   ETHEUR E3   ETHBTC E3   ETHEUR E3_ETHBTC E3
...     ...     ...     ...
```

The second one is a multi-index dataframe providing historic data, having the symbol as level 0 index and time as a level 1 index. This specific structure is desired (and given by some other library) as not every symbol has data for every point in time.

```
                                    close       high        low         open        volume
symbol      time                    
ETHEUR E3   2021-01-18 04:41:00     988.730000  988.730000  988.726611  988.726611  8.404723
            2021-01-18 04:42:00     988.730000  988.730000  988.726611  988.726611  0.000000
            2021-01-18 04:43:00     988.730000  988.730000  988.726611  988.726611  0.000000
            2021-01-18 04:44:00     990.620360  990.620360  989.640000  989.640000  0.158394
            2021-01-18 04:45:00     995.010000  995.010000  995.010000  995.010000  0.006665
...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...
ANTETH E3   2021-01-18 04:56:00     0.003745    0.003745    0.003745    0.003745    0.000000
            2021-01-18 04:57:00     0.003745    0.003745    0.003745    0.003745    0.000000
            2021-01-18 04:58:00     0.003745    0.003745    0.003745    0.003745    0.000000
            2021-01-18 04:59:00     0.003745    0.003745    0.003745    0.003745    0.000000
            2021-01-18 05:00:00     0.003745    0.003745    0.003745    0.003745    0.000000
```

My goal is to assemble a pair-wise history as follows, with 'X' and 'Y' containing the data from the previous dataframe for the first and second symbol of the pair:

```
                                                X                                                           Y
                                                close       high        low         open        volume      close       high        low         open        volume
handle                  time                                        
ETHEUR E3_XMRUSD E3     2021-01-18 04:41:00     988.730000  988.730000  988.726611  988.726611  8.404723    153.450000  153.450000  153.250000  153.250000  0.000000
                        2021-01-18 04:42:00     988.730000  988.730000  988.726611  988.726611  0.000000    153.450000  153.450000  153.250000  153.250000  0.000000
                        2021-01-18 04:43:00     988.730000  988.730000  988.726611  988.726611  0.000000    153.450000  153.450000  153.250000  153.250000  0.000000
                        2021-01-18 04:44:00     990.620360  990.620360  989.640000  989.640000  0.158394    153.450000  153.450000  153.250000  153.250000  0.000000
                        2021-01-18 04:45:00     995.010000  995.010000  995.010000  995.010000  0.006665    153.860000  153.860000  153.360000  153.360000  4.845876
...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...
EOSETH E3_ANTETH E3     2021-01-18 04:56:00     0.002259    0.002259    0.002259    0.002259    0.000000    0.003745    0.003745    0.003745    0.003745    0.000000
                        2021-01-18 04:57:00     0.002259    0.002259    0.002259    0.002259    0.000000    0.003745    0.003745    0.003745    0.003745    0.000000
                        2021-01-18 04:58:00     0.002259    0.002259    0.002259    0.002259    0.000000    0.003745    0.003745    0.003745    0.003745    0.000000
                        2021-01-18 04:59:00     0.002259    0.002259    0.002259    0.002259    0.000000    0.003745    0.003745    0.003745    0.003745    0.000000
                        2021-01-18 05:00:00     0.002259    0.002259    0.002259    0.002259    0.000000    0.003745    0.003745    0.003745    0.003745    0.000000
```

This pair-wise history is used for further time-series style calculations between the two symbols.

Currently, I use the following code to generate the shown dataframe:

```py
def assemble_pairs_from_history(history):
    # Build unique pair combinations from symbols
    pair_tuples = list(combinations(history.index.unique('symbol'), 2))
    pair_info = pd.DataFrame(pair_tuples, columns=['X', 'Y'])
    # Designate a handle for each combination
    pair_info['handle'] = pair_info['X'].str.cat(pair_info['Y'], sep="_")
    
    display(pair_info)
    display(history)
    
    # Iterate over all pair combinations, assembling a dict of historical data DFs for X and Y symbol of the pair
    pair_history = {}
    for i, pi in pair_info.iterrows():
        pair_history[pi.handle] = pd.concat([history.loc[pi.X], history.loc[pi.Y]], axis=1, keys=['X', 'Y'])
        # Clean the time series so that only rows having values for both symbols of the pair remain
        pair_history[pi.handle].dropna(inplace=True)
    
    
    # Assemble into one big dataframe, index by handle -> time with X and Y top level columns
    pair_history = pd.concat(pair_history.values(), keys=pair_history.keys(), names=['handle'])

    display(pair_history)
```

The issue with this code is that the performance is pretty bad, with the iterrows() and subsequent concat() part taking 10 seconds for a result dataframe size of 5000 rows.

I already tried various combinations of apply(), join() and merge() as well as building a multiindex manually, but was not able to achieve the desired output format.

How can the performance of this task be improved?

Comment: Are you able to provide some sample data that you can provide to help test? I suspect this should be doable using a combination of merging and transforming.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you need the multi index for the columns, but would something like this be what you're looking for?

Given the following two input dataframes

| X | Y | handle |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ETHEUR E3 | XMRUSD E3 | ETHEUR E3_XMRUSD E3 |
| ETHEUR E3 | TRXETH E3 | ETHEUR E3_TRXETH E3 |
| ETHEUR E3 | ETHUSD E3 | ETHEUR E3_ETHUSD E3 |
| ETHEUR E3 | BTCEUR E3 | ETHEUR E3_BTCEUR E3 |
| ETHEUR E3 | ETHBTC E3 | ETHEUR E3_ETHBTC E3 |

| symbol | time | close | high | low | open | volume |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ETHEUR E3 | 2021-01-18 04:41:00 | 988.73 | 988.73 | 988.727 | 988.727 | 8.40472 |
| ETHEUR E3 | 2021-01-18 04:42:00 | 988.73 | 988.73 | 988.727 | 988.727 | 0 |
| ETHEUR E3 | 2021-01-18 04:43:00 | 988.73 | 988.73 | 988.727 | 988.727 | 0 |
| ETHEUR E3 | 2021-01-18 04:44:00 | 990.62 | 990.62 | 989.64 | 989.64 | 0.158394 |
| ETHEUR E3 | 2021-01-18 04:45:00 | 995.01 | 995.01 | 995.01 | 995.01 | 0.006665 |
| ANTETH E3 | 2021-01-18 04:56:00 | 0.003745 | 0.003745 | 0.003745 | 0.003745 | 0 |
| ANTETH E3 | 2021-01-18 04:57:00 | 0.003745 | 0.003745 | 0.003745 | 0.003745 | 0 |
| ANTETH E3 | 2021-01-18 04:58:00 | 0.003745 | 0.003745 | 0.003745 | 0.003745 | 0 |
| ANTETH E3 | 2021-01-18 04:59:00 | 0.003745 | 0.003745 | 0.003745 | 0.003745 | 0 |
| ANTETH E3 | 2021-01-18 05:00:00 | 0.003745 | 0.003745 | 0.003745 | 0.003745 | 0 |

you can use `pandas.merge` to join the tables twice for each of the currency pairs.

```
combined = (
    df1
    # join data for first currency pair
    .merge(df2, how="left", left_on="X", right_on="symbol")
    # join data for second currency pair
    .merge(df2, how="left", left_on=["Y", "time"], right_on=["symbol", "time"], suffixes=("_X", "_Y"))
)

# get columns names for multi index
cols = [x.split("_")[::-1] if "_" in x else ["", x] for x in combined.columns]
# set new column names
combined.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(list(zip(*cols)))
# select required columns
combined = combined[[x for x in combined.columns if x[1] in ["handle", "time", "close", "high", "low", "open", "volume"]]]
```

Which results in the following dataframe:

| ('', 'handle') | ('', 'time') | ('X', 'close') | ('X', 'high') | ('X', 'low') | ('X', 'open') | ('X', 'volume') | ('Y', 'close') | ('Y', 'high') | ('Y', 'low') | ('Y', 'open') | ('Y', 'volume') |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ETHEUR E3_XMRUSD E3 | 2021-01-18 04:41:00 | 988.73 | 988.73 | 988.727 | 988.727 | 8.40472 | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan |
| ETHEUR E3_XMRUSD E3 | 2021-01-18 04:42:00 | 988.73 | 988.73 | 988.727 | 988.727 | 0 | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan |
| ETHEUR E3_XMRUSD E3 | 2021-01-18 04:43:00 | 988.73 | 988.73 | 988.727 | 988.727 | 0 | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan |
| ETHEUR E3_XMRUSD E3 | 2021-01-18 04:44:00 | 990.62 | 990.62 | 989.64 | 989.64 | 0.158394 | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan |
| ETHEUR E3_XMRUSD E3 | 2021-01-18 04:45:00 | 995.01 | 995.01 | 995.01 | 995.01 | 0.006665 | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan |